# SetEnvironmentVariable doesn’t work for %var%\target.extension

Tags: c#, environment-variables

```
string var1 = "drive";
string var2 = "parent";
string var3 = "testpath";
string var4 = "mypath";
string var5 = "partpath";
string var6 = "mypath2";
string path1 = "E:\\";
string path2 = "%drive%ParentFolder";
string path3 = "%parent%\\Parent.txt";
string path4 = "E:\\ParentFolder\\Parent.txt";
string path5 = "E:\\ParentFolder\\";
string path6 = "%partpath%Parent.txt";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(var1, path1, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(var2, path2, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(var3, path3, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(var4, path4, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(var5, path5, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(var6, path6, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

If I were to start %testpath% (which is var3 path3), result: %parent%Parent.txt not found

If I were to start %mypath% (which is var4 path4), result: successfully open Parent.txt

If I were to start %mypath2% (which is var6 path6), result: %parent%Parent.txt not found

It appears it has problem using %var%\application.exe set through SetEnvironmentVariable.

Anyone shares the same problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do replacement with getenvironmentalvariable value if the recursive logic isn't working.

Comment: given that this setting environment variables may come in at different sequence (race condition), getenvironmentvariable may not be able to get the resultant value first and set it for the subsequent variable.